# Howto get a table as a out parameter in oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am trying to cast the out parameter of an oracle procedure call to a object. It does not work, because - as I understand it - I need to define a map, which tells the method how to cast it. If the map is emtpy or not correcty filled, it defaults to an Objekt of the type STRUCT - which is wrong in my case.

I have build a sample, which should illustrate the problem:

```
-- Procedure in database
PROCEDURE myprocedure (
inputParam                IN       VARCHAR2 (4),
outputOne                 OUT outputOneSQLType
outputTwo                 OUT outputTwoSQLType);

-- inside of a package
inside a package mypackage

-- first type
create or replace
TYPE outputOneSQLType IS TABLE OF tableOneExample

-- table of type
create or replace
TYPE tableOneExample AS OBJECT (
      somethingOne                 VARCHAR2 (4)
     ,somethingTwo        NUMBER (12)
)

//java from here

import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT;
import oracle.sql.STRUCT;
...
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection oracleConn = (oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection) con.getMetaData().getConnection();
final OracleCallableStatement storedProc = (OracleCallableStatement)oracleConn.prepareCall("{call mypackage.myprocedure("+
                ":inputParam, :outputOne, :outputTwo)}");

storedProc.setString("inputParam", "SomeValue");

storedProc.registerOutParameter("outputOne",  OracleTypes.STRUCT, "OUTPUTONESQLTYPE");
storedProc.registerOutParameter("outputTwo",  OracleTypes.STRUCT, "OUTPUTTWOSQLTYPE");

storedProc.execute();

//So far so good

//now I am lost - I need to define the map to get the object? 
//What should be inside the map?
Hashtable newMap = new Hashtable();

newMap.put("outputOneSQLType", ?????.class);

//If the map is empty, it defaults to STRUCT...
final STRUCT myObject =  (STRUCT)storedProc.getObject("somethingOne",newMap);
// myObject.getBytes() gives me an object... but I cannot cast it to anything
```

Because of the faulty map, I cannot use someting like:

```
final MyClass myObject =  (MyClass)storedProc.getObject("somethingOne",newMap);
```

How should I fill the map?

**Edit 1**

The entries in the oracle database can not be changed. I am just allowed to use them. Therefor

```
stmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.ARRAY, "OUTPUTONESQLTYPE");
```

does not work. Because a exception is thrown as soon as I do not use "OracleTypes.STRUCT". It seems that inside of outputOneSQLType there is an object of type "OracleTypeCOLLECTION"

When I try

```
 Hashtable newMap = new Hashtable();
newMap.put("outputOneSQLType",OracleTypeCOLLECTION.class);
final OracleTypeCOLLECTION myObject =  (OracleTypeCOLLECTION)storedProc.getObject("somethingOne",newMap);
```

I get an exception: `InstantiationException: oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeCOLLECTION`

@DazzaL: I will try to define a SQLDATA interface. Maybe that will be the solution

**SOLUTION**

1. The prepared statement should be something like "begin package.procedure(...); end;" and **NOT** "{call package.procedure(...)})
2. A SQLData Interface is needed.

@DazzaL: you rule! Thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to define a sqldata object to map this.

documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraarr.htm#JJDBC28574

for example:

```
SQL> create or replace TYPE tableOneExample AS OBJECT (
  2        somethingOne                 VARCHAR2 (4)
  3       ,somethingTwo        NUMBER (12)
  4  );
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace TYPE outputOneSQLType IS TABLE OF tableOneExample;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace PROCEDURE myprocedure (
  2  inputParam                IN       VARCHAR2,
  3  outputOne                 OUT outputOneSQLType)
  4  as
  5  begin
  6  outputOne  := outputOneSQLType(tableOneExample('a', 1), tableOneExample('b', 2));
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.
```

now we we define the SQLDATA interface:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TestArr implements SQLData
 {
  private String sql_type;

  public String attrOne;
  public int    attrTwo;

  public TestArr() 
  { 
  }
  public TestArr (String sql_type, String attrOne, int attrTwo)
  {
    this.sql_type = sql_type;
    this.attrOne = attrOne;
    this.attrTwo = attrTwo;
   }

  // define a get method to return the SQL type of the object
  public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException
  { 
    return sql_type; 
  } 

  // define the required readSQL() method 
  public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName)
    throws SQLException
  {
    sql_type = typeName;

    attrOne = stream.readString();
    attrTwo = stream.readInt();
  }  
  // define the required writeSQL() method 
  public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream)
    throws SQLException
  { 
    stream.writeString(attrOne);
    stream.writeInt(attrTwo);
  }
}
```

make sure the inputs and ordering of the stream writes/reads are the same as your oracle type, as any inconsistencies will give internal representation errors.

then in the main class, you'd map this as follows:

```
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("begin myprocedure(?,?); end;");
stmt.setString(1, "foo");
stmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.ARRAY, "OUTPUTONESQLTYPE"); // YOUR ARRAY TYPE (TO MATCH THE API OUTPUT), NOT OBJECT
stmt.execute();
Array arr = stmt.getArray (2);
Map map = conn.getTypeMap();
map.put("TABLEONEEXAMPLE", Class.forName("TestArr")); // YOUR OBJECT TYPE, NOT ARRAY.
Object[] values = (Object[]) arr.getArray();
for (int i=0; i < values.length; i++)
{
  TestArr a = (TestArr)values[i];
  System.out.println("somethingOne: " + a.attrOne);
  System.out.println("somethingTwo: " + a.attrTwo);
}
```

the result bieng:

```
M:\Documents\Sample Code\1>javac TestArr.java

M:\Documents\Sample Code\1>javac ArrayTest.java
Note: ArrayTest.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

M:\Documents\Sample Code\SQLComplexArray>java ArrayTest
Opening Oracle connection...done.
somethingOne: a
somethingTwo: 1
somethingOne: b
somethingTwo: 2
```

Comment: Thx.  I will try to define a SQLDATA interface. Maybe that will be the solution.

Comment: Worked for me well, Posting my post too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253448/java-plsql-call-table-of-records-from-java/25274486#25274486