# Java- PLSQL- Call Table of records from java

Tags: java, plsql

PLSQL package-procedure declarations

```
TYPE custom_type IS TABLE OF single_rec_type;

 TYPE single_rec_type IS RECORD(
 //id, name etc
 )
```

**Problem:**

But custom_type has no direct Java type representation [like `OracleTypes.CLOB` or `OracleTypes.CURSOR`]
because custom_type is a PLSQL type and not a SQL type.

When I googled, I came across these two options: 
To represent it ,

(1) create a SQL TYPE from procedure(or a wrapper PLSQL function) that we can bind from java.
Reference: [java - passing array in oracle stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399750/java-passing-array-in-oracle-stored-procedure/1399898#1399898)

(2)  Register the output parameter with our type and use SQLData object to represent a record.
Reference: [Howto get a table as a out parameter in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801183/howto-get-a-table-as-a-out-parameter-in-oracle)

```
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(8, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "custom_type");
```

On doing this, I get the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: MYDB_OWNER.custom_type
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.initMetadata(OracleTypeADT.java:554)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.init(OracleTypeADT.java:471)
```

One suggestion was to declare the custom_type TYPE inside the schema, instead of declaring inside the package.
or by creating public synonym and giving grants.

**Question** - Regarding the second approach, is it correct practice to declare any custom type in schema level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, That's the only way it works. I followed the link mentioned in second approach
[Howto get a table as a out parameter in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801183/howto-get-a-table-as-a-out-parameter-in-oracle)

and it worked. The Package level changes included (1) Declaring the `custom_type` and `single_rec_type` in schema level [as global, not inside the package] and (2) Replacing `IS RECORD` with `AS OBJECT`.

The Java code changes apart from what was mentioned in the link, includes giving the complete name for the class in `map.put("SINGLE_REC_TYPE", Class.forName("com.example.SRecord"));`

Another thing to notice is that in that example, it mentioned `stream.readString();`. If you read the API, it says *'Reads the next attribute in the stream and returns it as a String in the Java programming language.'* . So if you have three attributes inside the object, then use the method three times like this

```
id = stream.readString();
name = stream.readString();
designation = stream.readString();
```

Another point is well mentioned in that post; Regarding the datatypes of attributes inside the object. If there are type mismatch, you get internal representation errors.

eg: correct way:

*SRecord.java*

```
public String id; \\varchar in plsql procedure
public String name; \\varchar in plsql procedure
```