# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: pakagename.sqlTypename

Tags: java, oracle

I am getting invalid name pattern exception when executing oracle function. which is return sql type as record which is present under package. If the type is present in Types directory it is working fine. But I am not able to execute if it is present in package directory. Please help me regarding this.

```
create or replace PACKAGE pkg_name 

TYPE sqlTypeName 
IS 
RECORD(
firstVariable NUMBER,
secondVariable VARCHAR);

TYPE sqlTypeName_c is TABLE Of sqlTypeName INDEX BY pls_integer;

FUNCTION functionName() RETURN sqlTypeName_c
```

In java code:

```
        Map typeMap = conn.getTypeMap();
        typeMap.put("sqlTypeName_c", Array.class);
        typeMap.put("sqlTypeName", Struct.class);


        CallableStatement clstmt= null;
        clstmt = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call pkg_name.functionName() }");

        clstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.ARRAY, "pkg_name.sqlTypeName_c");

        clstmt.executeUpdate();

        Array returnvalue = clstmt.getArray(1);
```

Comment: Try to add name of schema in front of your package, like schema.pkg_name.sqlTypeName_c

Comment: according to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589155/invalid-name-pattern-when-trying-to-pass-custom-oracle-type-object-mapping/21589348) it will be solved if you caps ALL of your Type name.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work since the type is declared in the package. You will need to declare the sqlTypeName TYPE inside the schema.

Here are some of the questions which touch upon this issue - 
[Java- PLSQL- Call Table of records from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253448/java-plsql-call-table-of-records-from-java/25274486#25274486)

[Fetch Oracle table type from stored procedure using JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410452/fetch-oracle-table-type-from-stored-procedure-using-jdbc)